# Python: Inserting variables into a string without order

Tags: python

Is it possible to inject variable values into strings without knowing the order?
I'm familiar with

```
"% world" % "Hello"
```

syntax, but is there anything comparable to

```
string = "Order id %{order.id}, price: %price" % (price, order)
```

I'm asking because I'd like to have a list of strings with inconsistant use of variables, and their placement, and I want to substitute them all inside of a function.

Comment: There may be a dupe of this lying around somewhere, but the linked dupe doesn't consider the case of attribute access within the string.  `"{order.id}".format(order=...)`

Comment: You're right; it's somewhat similar, and the answer kinda covers it, but I never ran upon that question because of the various ways of phrasing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.format`:

```
>>> class order(object) : pass
... 
>>> a = order()
>>> a.id=3
>>> "{order.id}".format(order=a)
'3'
>>> "{order.id} and then a {foo} hit the {baz} ".format(baz="fan",foo="rocket",order=a) 
'3 and then a rocket hit the fan '
```

This uses keyword arguments which are unordered by nature.

Comment: +1. This is actually the suggested way now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a *list* of strings, or a dict?  If it's an actual list, then you can't possibly do anything useful, because you don't know what value is what.  But if it's a dict, you have a few options.  Using the `%` operator:

```
"Order number %(order_id)s, price: %(price)s" % dict(order_id=3, price=4.00)
```

But I notice you have `order.id` in your example, which sounds like it means `order` is some custom object.  In that case you can use the newer `.format` method, which lets you look up attributes right in the string:

```
"Order number {order.id}, price: {price}".format(order=..., price=...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that `order` and `price` are integers. You can use any other format specifier in place of `d`. (i.e. `f` for float)

```
string = "Order id %(order)d, price: %(price)d" % {'price': price, 'order': order}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't think that the old style has any way of accessing an attribute.  e.g. `"%(order.id)d"` ??

Comment: Correct. You would have to use `order.id` in the dict.